# Run command on cisco switch

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cisco

I made the below script to login to a switch and execute a command. as soon as i execute the script it logins to switch and exits without running the command.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 3000

spawn bash -c "ssh ananair@10.60.255.100"

expect "*assword:"

send "pass@123\n"

expect "*#"

send "show interfaces status"
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 shebangs ? Yous should only need the expect one. Also, if you want to run an ssh session with password authentication, you should have a look at `sshpass`

Comment: Removed and tried still the same..
Authenthication is working its loging into switch. while exiting i can see the switch hostname

Comment: Have you tried writting `send "show interfaces status\r"` instead ?

Comment: tried that still the same.. this is the output.

    `[root@cap-nwmon-01 anand]# ./migrate.sh`

   ` spawn bash -c ssh ananair@10.60.255.100`

   ` Password:`

    `CAP-S12-LAB-CAT-SW01#[root@cap-nwmon-01 anand]#`

Comment: What happens if you add ANOTHER command after the `show` one in your script? `exit`, for example?

Comment: no commands are executing after the sending password. it comes to the switch prompt and exits

Comment: That switch prompt looks like one you'd get after the `enable` command, which I don't see in your expect script. Should you have `expect "*>"` instead?

Comment: this user has highest priviledge. so it directly logins to enable mode

Comment: In short anything after `send "pass@123\n"` this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the missing `\n` in your final `send`. If you simply `send "string"`, then expect never hits Enter at the end of the command, And since there's no final `expect`, it figures its work is done, and exits, probably even before it has a chance to echo the command it sent but never executed.

Consider the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 3000

spawn ssh switchhostname          # no need to run this inside a shell

expect "ssword:"

send "1ns3cur3\n"                 # it would be better to use key based auth...

expect "#"

send "term len 0\n"               # tell the switch to avoid "More" prompts

expect "#"

send "show interfaces status\n"   # note the final "\n"

expect "#"                        # don't quit until the "show" command finishes
```

You might also consider getting access to this information via SNMP.

Comment: Thanks Bro.. the final expect "#" statement did the trick.. which was missing in mine. i never thought i would require the final expect..

Answer (score 0):

try \r instead of \n

I have my expect script that I use to login to my cisco switches for me. and then I use interact from the expect script that leaves me at the cisco prompt.

I would need to rework it to not show passwords but I can definitely help you out.

I didn't need timeouts in mine.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
proc enable {} {
 expect "assword:" {
  send "<enable password>\r"
  expect "#" {
  }
 }
}

proc login {} {
 send "<login password>\r"
 expect {
  "failed" {
   send "<username>\r"
   enable
  }
  ">" {
   send "en\r"
   enable
  }
  "#" {
 }}
}
set user_computer_attached [lindex $argv 0]
set user_computer [split $user_computer_attached "@"]
spawn ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 \
-oGlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no $user_computer_attached
expect_after eof {
  wait
  spawn telnet [lindex $user_computer 1]
  expect "name:"
  send [lindex $user_computer 0]
  send "\r"
  expect "assword:" {
   login
  }
}
expect "assword:" {
 login
}
interact
```

Comment: Thanks bro.. this will be a lot useful in my future ios scipting